# Ошибка при работе с потоками.

Tags: filestream, c++

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь побайтно скопировать картинку, почти получается... В выходном файле-картинке происходит смещение... Ну, идут байты 00 00 cc аа сс а на выходе откуда-то дописывается 00 и получается 00 00 **00** сс aa cc. Откуда он берется? Ставил чекпоинты, в буффер символов вроде всё правильно заносится...

Вот часть кода:

```
unsigned char ch[1000000];
    int hight, wight;
    FILE *stream,*stream3;
    stream = fopen("w.bmp", "rb");
    stream3 = fopen("file2.bmp","w");
    if ((stream==NULL)||(stream3==NULL)){
        cout << "Can't open file!\n";
    }
    int i=0;
    while(!feof(stream)){
            //putc(ch[i]=getc(stream),stream3);
        ch[i]=getc(stream);//В массив всё!!!
        i++;
    }
    i-=2;//Всё верно!!!
    int counter=i;
    fseek(stream3,0,SEEK_SET);// в начало файла//54-начало файла ставим 0

    int y=0;
    while(y<=counter){
        putc(ch[y],stream3);//Вроде как не работает...
        y++;
    }
 Вод фрагмент из winhex:
do:    posle
38 c4  38 00
39 ab  39 c4
40 ..  40 ab
```

И вот еще, студия иногда говорила stakc overflow... 
Что это за такая ошибка???

Comment: Гугл вам поможет.

Answer (score 3):

> stakc overflow
>
> unsigned char ch[1000000];

Ну не удивительно. Читайте про динамическую память.

Comment: А нельзя статический массив такого размера сделать?

Comment: Можно и зайца научить курить (C). Статический - попробуйте, но сначала научитесь отличать статику от автоматических переменных, которые создаются на стеке...

Comment: Работать с динамически выделяемой памятью(массивами) я умею, интересно почему происходит переполнение стека? Про тонкости я мало что знаю... Приложению при запуске отводится ограниченная(не раширяемая память)? Если да, как можно ее увеличить? В сети про такие тонкости особо не глаголят... во всяком случае я не встречал...

Comment: Потому что на стеке выделяется кусок памяти, размерами превышающий размер стека. Ваш Капитан Очевидность.

>Если да, как можно ее увеличить?

Увеличить размер стека (см. настройки компилятора). Один раз, в качестве эксперимента, после чего забыть про такие глупости раз и навсегда.

Comment: Вы выделяете миллион байт на стеке, и удивляетесь, почему происходит переполнение? Нет, вы всё же почитайте про автоматические переменные, это не тонкости, это основы.

Answer (score 0):

[первая ссылка в яндексе](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932909)

Несмотря на кривой перевод вполне читабельна